# Need to add Spaces at certain Indexes

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexoutofrangeexception

So this is data i have,

```
s = [2, 8, 15, 23, 28, 43, 47, 55, 63, 72, 79, 82, 89, 97, 102, 112, 120, 125, 131, 141, 148, 156, 163, 167, 180, 188, 193, 210, 222, 227]
```

These are the index position where i need to add spaces,

```
d = 'CCCarbonCopyCAIComputerAidedInstructionCDMACodeDivisionMultipleAccessCRTCathodeRayTubeCADComputerAidedDesignCADDComputerAidedDesignDraftingCDCompactDiskCDRWCompactDiskRewritableCAMComputerAidedManufacturingCROMComputerizedRangeMotionCDROMCompactDiskReadOnlyMemory'
```

My overall goal is split the string in such a way that the Shotforms and the Longforms are seperated,

For EX: This is the output I'm trying to get

```
CC Carbon Copy CAI Computer Aided Instruction
```

and so on.....

I have calculated the indexes by doing this,

```
s = []
for i in range(0, len(d)):
    if d[i].isupper() and d[i+1].islower() and d[i+2].islower():
        s.append(i)
```

When I individually try and add the space using the index, I get an output,

```
d[0:s[0]] + ' ' + d[s[0]:]
```

I get the following, which is correct

```
'CC CarbonCopyCAIComputerAidedInstructionCDMACodeDivisionMultipleAccessCRTCathodeRayTube
```

But, when I try and iterate over the indexes, i get List out of Range

```
temp = []
for i in s:
    print(i)
    temp.append(d[0:s[i]] + ' ' + d[s[i]:])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 4, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Are you looking for help creating the list `s` or just using it to split up the string?

Comment: s is not being created correctly as well, since the requested output is: CC Carbon Copy CAI Computer Aided Instruction, but e.g. the third index is 15 and not 12.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing the indexes, you could directly store the character to print as follows:

```py
l = []
for i in range(0, len(d)):
    if d[i].isupper() and d[i + 1].islower() and d[i + 2].islower():
        l.append(" ")
    l.append(d[i])
output = "".join(l)
```

However, there are still some problems with this code, it seems like you miss cases like: "InstructionCDMA", "AccessCRT"... 
Moreover, you can get some `IndexError: string index out of range`...

To fix both, you could do:

```py
l = []
for i in range(0, len(d) - 2):
    if d[i].isupper() and d[i + 1].islower() and d[i + 2].islower():
        l.append(" ")
    l.append(d[i])
    if d[i].islower() and d[i + 1].isupper() and d[i + 2].isupper():
        l.append(" ")
output = "".join(l)
```

Comment: Yes @Tomerikoo, the list of indexes is given but it obtained only in order to add the spaces where it's needed. Instead of iterating through the whole string to find indexes and the to insert the spaces, I suggest to do both at once.

Comment: As you can see I deleted the comment as the question is not clear. From the code it seems that OP is actually creating `s` and it is not given, so my comment was wrong and your answer is fine! :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a different approach would be simpler. Depending on how consistent your data is you may be able to `re.split()` on capitalized words `r'([A-Z][a-z]+)` and capture the delimiter. Something like:

```
import re

d = 'CCCarbonCopyCAIComputerAidedInstructionCDMACodeDivisionMultipleAccessCRTCathodeRayTubeCADComputerAidedDesignCADDComputerAidedDesignDraftingCDCompactDiskCDRWCompactDiskRewritableCAMComputerAidedManufacturingCROMComputerizedRangeMotionCDROMCompactDiskReadOnlyMemory'

out = " ".join(filter(len, re.split(r'([A-Z][a-z]+)', d)))
```

This will give you:

`'CC Carbon Copy CAI Computer Aided Instruction CDMA Code Division Multiple Access CRT Cathode Ray Tube CAD Computer Aided Design CADD Computer Aided Design Drafting CD Compact Disk CDRW Compact Disk Rewritable CAM Computer Aided Manufacturing CROM Computerized Range Motion CDROM Compact Disk Read Only Memory'`

This seems to work on your given string, but there could be edge cases if your data is different.

Answer (score 0):

Notice the following:

```
s = []
for i in range(0, len(d)):
    if d[i].isupper() and d[i+1].islower() and d[i+2].islower():
        s.append(i)
```

Here, `i` goes from `0` to `len(d)`. What do you think happens when you call `d[len(d)+1]`?

Answer (score 0):

You should first build a list with all the words, based on index. Then, the `join` function will do the job.

```
s = [2, 8, 15, 23, 28, 43, 47, 55, 63, 72, 79, 82, 89, 97, 102, 112, 120, 125, 131, 141, 148, 156, 163, 167, 180, 188, 193, 210, 222, 227]
d = 'CCCarbonCopyCAIComputerAidedInstructionCDMACodeDivisionMultipleAccessCRTCathodeRayTubeCADComputerAidedDesignCADDComputerAidedDesignDraftingCDCompactDiskCDRWCompactDiskRewritableCAMComputerAidedManufacturingCROMComputerizedRangeMotionCDROMCompactDiskReadOnlyMemory'

last_elem = 0
lst = []
for el in s:
    lst.append(d[last_elem:el])
    last_elem = el
' '.join(lst)
```

output:
`'CC Carbon CopyCAI Computer Aided InstructionCDMA Code Division Multiple AccessCRT Cathode Ray TubeCAD Computer Aided DesignCADD Computer Aided Design DraftingCD Compact DiskCDRW Compact Disk RewritableCAM Computer Aided ManufacturingCROM Computerized Range'`

Comment: You forgot to insert the last word last_elem to the list.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the string to list and then insert spaces and then transform back.

```
s = [2, 8, 15, 23, 28, 43, 47, 55, 63, 72, 79, 82, 89, 97, 102, 112, 120, 125, 131, 141, 148, 156, 163, 167, 180, 188, 193, 210, 222, 227]
d = 'CCCarbonCopyCAIComputerAidedInstructionCDMACodeDivisionMultipleAccessCRTCathodeRayTubeCADComputerAidedDesignCADDComputerAidedDesignDraftingCDCompactDiskCDRWCompactDiskRewritableCAMComputerAidedManufacturingCROMComputerizedRangeMotionCDROMCompactDiskReadOnlyMemory'
d = list(d)
for index,i in enumerate(s):
    d.insert(index + i, " ")
d = ''.join(d)
print(d)
```

Output:

```
CC Carbon CopyCAI Computer Aided InstructionCDMA Code Division Multiple AccessCRT Cathode Ray TubeCAD Computer Aided DesignCADD Computer Aided Design DraftingCD Compact DiskCDRW Compact Disk RewritableCAM Computer Aided ManufacturingCROM Computerized Range MotionCDROMCompactDiskReadOnlyMemory
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do everything in one go using regular expressions, without having to calculate your list of indices first.

First, we separate the short forms and long forms parts, then we add spaces between the words in the long forms.

We get your data in a more structured form than what you want:

```
import re

d = 'CCCarbonCopyCAIComputerAidedInstructionCDMACodeDivisionMultipleAccessCRTCathodeRayTubeCADComputerAidedDesignCADDComputerAidedDesignDraftingCDCompactDiskCDRWCompactDiskRewritableCAMComputerAidedManufacturingCROMComputerizedRangeMotionCDROMCompactDiskReadOnlyMemory'

lst = re.findall(r'([A-Z]+)((?:[A-Z][a-z]+)+)', d)
# [('CC', 'CarbonCopy'),
#  ('CAI', 'ComputerAidedInstruction'), ...

lst = [(abbr, re.sub(r'([a-z])(?=[A-Z])', r'\1 ', long)) for abbr, long in lst]
print(lst)
# [('CC', 'Carbon Copy'),
#  ('CAI', 'Computer Aided Instruction'), ...
```

If you really want everything together in a single string, losing that structure:

```
joined = ' '.join([item for tup in lst for item in tup])
print(joined)
# CC Carbon Copy CAI Computer Aided Instruction CDMA Code Division Multiple Access ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are iterating over the list elements and still accessing it through index. Which is wrong.

```
for i in s:
    print(i) # this will iterate over the list, in that case you do not need indexing.

for i in range(len(s)):
    print(s[i])
```

You need to understand difference between the two. 
For ref: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/iterate-over-a-list-in-python/

For your problem, You may try this -

```
words = []   
for i in range(len(s)-1):
    words.append(d[s[i]:s[i+1]])
" ".join(words)
```